# Show that if $a \sim b$, then $C(a) = C(b)$ where $C(x)$ is the equivalence class containing $x$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning, equivalence-relations

**I'm working through a textbook on my own, so I don't want the full answer. I'm only looking for a [hint](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11258/how-should-i-ask-questions-that-i-just-need-hints-on) on this problem.**

> Show that if $a \sim b$, then $C(a) = C(b)$ where $C(x)$ is the equivalence class containing $x$.

I'm reading through Paul Sally's *Tools of the Trade*, and he gives this problem as an example in a theorem. An equivalence class is defined like this: If $a \in X$, then we write $C(a) = \lbrace b \in X \mid b \sim a \rbrace$. The proof is as "Transitivity" and that's it, but I'm not sure how to use transitivity to prove it. Here's what I have so far:

Let $a, b \in X$ be arbitrary elements of $X$. If $a \sim b$, then $a \in C(b)$ by definition. But, if $a \sim b$, then $b \sim a$ by symmetry, so $b \in C(a)$. This is where I get stuck. Since $a, b$ are arbitrary elements in $X$, can I just immediately conclude that $C(a) = C(b)$ for any $a,b \in X$ where $a \sim b$. I'm not sure how to use transitivity here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us introduce some more variety in the letters used. For $x \in X$, define $C(x)$ by:

$$C(x) = \{y \in X\mid y \sim x\}$$

Hence:

$$C(a) = \{y \in X \mid y \sim a\}, \quad C(b) =\{y \in X\mid y \sim b\}$$

What does it mean for these to be equal? How does transitivity come into play when proving this?

Comment: This was a great hint. It's so easy (for me) to get lost in the notation that seeing it all cleared up was really helpful for me. Now I don't know which answer to check! This answer really cleared up the notation for me, and the other answer cleared up the use of transitivity for me.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $x\in C(a)$, then $x\sim a\sim b$, so ...

Comment: I think I get this. So if $y \in C(a)$, then $y \sim a$ (I'm using the notation of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/560430/93114)), so by the given ($a \sim b$) and transitivity, $y \sim a \sim b$, so $y \in C(b)$. Therefore $C(a) \subseteq C(b)$. Going the other way, if $y \in C(b)$, then $y \sim b \sim a$ by symmetry of $a \sim b$. That means that $y \in C(a)$, so $C(b) \subseteq C(a)$, so $C(a) = C(b)$. Right?

Comment: @Michael: Exactly right.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the hint!

Comment: @Michael: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Prove $C(a)\subseteq C(b)$, and $C(b)\subseteq C(a)$.

Comment: I don't know why I always forget to look at problems this way, since it's super useful. Thank you so much for the hint!